# NameError: name 'ScreenEA' is not defined

Tags: ida, idapython, error-messages

Part of Practical malware analysis Lab5, is to run a python script in IDA Pro

I have tried by going to Files-->Script command then I have pasted my python code:

```
sea = ScreenEA()

for i in range(0x00,0x50):
        b = Byte(sea+i)
        decoded_byte = b ^ 0x55
        PatchByte(sea+i,decoded_byte)
```

when I click Run it shows me this error:

> NameError: name 'ScreenEA' is not defined

.

PS: when I tried to upload the script file it also shows the same error

I have tried idc.ScreenEA just to see what will happen but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is a legacy API, deprecated in IDA 7.0 and [removed in IDA 7.4](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml). The new equivalent is `idc.get_screen_ea()` (or you can use `idc.here()` which still works).